# Using link_to helper to open a link in a new window

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How do you use the `link_to` helper to open a link in a new window?

Older versions of rails allowed you to use this option, but this no longer works:

```
<%= link_to('My Text', my_path, popup: true) %>
```

Answer (score 3):

It isn't as pretty, but this is how I got it to work:

```
<%= link_to('My Text', my_path, target: '_blank') %>
```